# Customize Django Log Entry Change_Message Field with the 3 Action Flags

Tags: django

Basically, I want to customize the change_message to make it more friendly, and show something in deletion action flag. Any approaches?

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jel5k.jpg)

This is the class I built in order to try and achieve this (and other things I had to do):

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.admin.models import LogEntry, DELETION, CHANGE
from django.utils.html import escape
from django.urls import reverse
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe

@admin.register(LogEntry)
class LogEntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    date_hierarchy = 'action_time'

    list_filter = [
        'user',
        'content_type',
        'action_flag'
    ]

    search_fields = [
        'object_repr',
        'change_message'
    ]

    list_display = [
        'action_time',
        'user',
        'content_type',
        'action_flag',
        'object_link',
        'change_message'
    ]

    def change_message(self, obj):
        return obj.get_change_message()

    def object_link(self, obj):
        if obj.action_flag == DELETION:
            link = escape(obj.object_repr)
        else:
            ct = obj.content_type
            link = '<a href="%s">%s</a>' % (
            reverse('admin:%s_%s_change' % (ct.app_label, ct.model), args=[obj.object_id]),
            escape(obj.object_repr),
        )
        return mark_safe(link)
    object_link.admin_order_field = "object_repr"
    object_link.short_description = "object"
```